# Using template literals in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, template-literals

So I'm making a shopping cart and I'm adding products dynamically, and each product have multiple elements of course but my problem is in the remove button and in the add amount, remove amount and the item quantity. Each of those has a class but I can't choose those elements because I'm commenting them out or removing them from the HTML. So is there a way to grab those elements by adding classes to them using template literals?

Here's my single product HTML:

```
<div class="cart-content">
  <!-- cart item -->
  <!-- <div class="cart-item">
    <img src="/img/higher-clouds.jpg" alt="product" srcset="" />
    <div>
      <h4>queen bed</h4>
      <h5>$9</h5>
      <span class="remove-item">Remove</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i>
      <p class="item-amount">1</p>
      <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
    </div>
  </div> -->
  <!-- end of cart item -->
</div>
```

And this is the javascript:

```
// add products to cart

const addBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("bag-btn");
for (let i = 0; i < addBtns.length; i++) {
  const btn = addBtns[i];
  btn.addEventListener("click", addToCart);
}

function addToCart(e) {
  const button = e.target;
  button.innerText = "In Cart";
  button.disabled = true;
  const title = button.parentElement.nextElementSibling.textContent;
  const price =
  button.parentElement.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.children[0].textContent;
  const img = button.parentElement.children[0].src;
  addItemToCart(title, price, img);
}

function addItemToCart(title, price, img) {
  const newRow = document.createElement("div");
  newRow.classList.add("cart-item");
  newRow.innerHTML = `
 <img src="${img}" alt="product" srcset="" />
  <div>
    <h4>${title}</h4>
    <h5>${price}</h5>
    <span class="remove-item">Remove</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i>
    <p class="item-amount">1</p>
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
  </div>`;
  cartContent.append(newRow);
}
```

How to add the classes (remove-item, fa-chevron-up, fa-chevron-down, item-amount) to their elements using template literals or any other way? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use `element.classList.add` to add classes to an element.

Comment: I did that and added the class ('cart-item') to the new div I created. But there's more elements inside the div, can I create them as well and append them to the div while adding their classes? @AbrarHossain

Comment: `document.createElement()` may be what you're looking for, if you can't construct your template string finely grained enough .. but you could also have bits like "<p${extra123}>${text123}</p>" in the literal and extra123 could be empty or contain " class='one two three'". TBH: I'm still unclear what your exact problem and/or desired result is.

Comment: @flowtron The problem is that I can't grab those elements because I removed them from the HTML since I'm adding them dynamically with JS. The desired result is that after I created the div, I can add more elements inside it such as the remove and quantity elements and add classes to them so I can select them and add event listeners.

Comment: Do I have to create all those elements with createElement(), add classes to them and append them to the div or is there another way?

Comment: if you want to grab one specific "item-amount" you need to first locate the "cart-item" - say you save it to `var curItem` and then you do `curItem.querySelector('.item-amount')`.

Comment: @flowtron I can't grab it because it's commented out, it's commented out because I'm not trying to hard code the cart products. Plus it's not one specific "item-amount", each product I add to the cart will have that same class. I edited the HTML, this is how my code looks. The whole cart-item div is commented out in the html and I'm adding it dynamically with JS using template literals.

Comment: Add all the classes before you append your elements to the parent element. That should work as expected. Also, in my opinion, it will be better than resorting to string literals

Comment: @AbrarHossain I actually was watching in the dev tools that when the new div is created, all the elements are already inside and they have their classes so I don't have to do anything lol But thanks for this info, it'll come in handy later on.

Answer (score 0):

use this pattern,
`attribute="${dynamicValue}"` notice the quotes(" ") around the template expression.

```js
  `<div>
    <i class="${dynamicString} ${dynamicString}"></i>
    <p class="${dynamicString}">1</p>
    <i class="${dynamicString}"></i>
  </div>`
```

Comment: So I can add the class with template literals like this...  <i class="${fa-chevron-up}"></i>  ?

Comment: Yes, Absolutely.

Comment: I actually was watching in the dev tools that when the new div is created, all the elements are already inside and they have their classes so I don't have to do anything lol But thanks for this info, it'll come in handy later on. @RahulDahal